# A sneak peek at the end of [preview]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview) has 107 questions with no consistent usage.

- Some refer to the OSX Preview.app (there's already [preview-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview-app))
- Quite a few refer to Microsoft Office or Adobe Reader document previews (there are already office-specific tags in use on most of the questions like [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010), or adobe specific [adobe-reader](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-reader) or [adobe-acrobat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-acrobat))
- Or video previews (could probably be tagged [video](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video))
- Or preview icons
- Or OS previews (but we have things like [windows-10-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview) already - speaking of deprecated tags *cough*)
- Or the *concept* of taking a quick look at a document in some cases.

You get the idea - the random usage makes it useless for categorizing questions.

Comment: There are 19 upvotes between the original question and this one.  The community has spoken.